# How to replace UTF-8 characters with their character names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8

I would like to create a bidirectional mapping of Unicode characters to the characters [a-z] and [0-9]. I thought about using the Unicode character names like *Left Curly Bracket* for *{*. Unfortunately I couldn't find a list of all UTF-8 characters with their character descriptions already prepared to be accessed within Ruby. The [Wikipedia contains a list of Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) and there is a [Unicode name list by the Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt). Before I start writing a parser for the list, I wanted to ask:

- is there are already an existing solution / gem to access the UTF-8 character names in Ruby?
- what would be the most efficient way to convert arbitrary UTF-8 strings using the UTF-8 character names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16647559/1128705) from [ovhaag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747202/ovhaag) to use [the Unicode Utils gem](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils), I came up with the following solution which is working for me:

```
require 'unicode_utils'
string       = %Q|Testing «ταБЬℓσ»: 1<2 & 4+1>3, now 20% off!|
mapping      = string.chars.collect {|c| UnicodeUtils.char_name(c).downcase}
name_to_byte = UnicodeUtils::NAME_MAP.invert
bytes        = mapping.collect {|c| name_to_byte[c.upcase]}
new_string   = bytes.pack('U*')
string==new_string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [unicode utils](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) gem

```
require "unicode_utils/char_name"
UnicodeUtils.char_name "ᾀ" => "GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA .."
```

For Alternatives look in [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) for "unicode .."

The [unicode](https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode) gem looks promising too

```
Unicode::decompose(str)
```

Comment: Oddly enough, just loading UnicodeUtils crashes my Ruby programs (latest stable as of February 2019).

Answer (score 2):

The [uniscribe gem](https://github.com/janlelis/uniscribe) does what you are asking for and it works with data from the current Unicode version. From Ruby, you can use it like this:

```
require "uniscribe/kernel_method"
uniscribe "  "
```

which will result in the following output:

```
1D578 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL M
1D58E ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL I
1D598 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL S
1D588 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL C
 0020 ├─ ] [        ├─ SPACE
1D580 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL U
1D593 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL N
1D58E ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL I
1D588 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL C
1D594 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL O
1D589 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL D
1D58A ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL E
 0020 ├─ ] [        ├─ SPACE
1D56E ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL C
1D58D ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL H
1D586 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL A
1D597 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL R
1D586 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL A
1D588 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL C
1D599 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL T
1D58A ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL E
1D597 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL R
1D598 ├─      ├─ MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL S
```

Under the hood it uses [unicode-name](https://github.com/janlelis/unicode-name) and [unicode-sequence_name](https://github.com/janlelis/unicode-sequence_name) which can also be used directly.